# How to configure ReactorNettyWebSocketClient with SPNEGO/Kerberos auth

Tags: java, websocket, spnego

I'm trying to run ReactorNettyWebSocketClient with SPNEGO/Kerberos auth but I don't know to make again an updated handshake call after received HTTP 401. I tried with retryWhen(). Unfortunately retry function always retry origin message and I want to add "Authorization" header with "Negotiation" + token.
My flow should look like below:

1. call wws
2. received 401 with WWW-Authenticate Negotiate
3. call again wss with "Authorization" header
4. received 101
5. start consuming data from wss